# Como hago para reemplazar "<html:" por "<" en todo el documento?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

El lenguaje HTML6 tiene este tipo de etiquetas    .

Como ni siquiera me funciona en ultima versión de Chrome y mucho menos en IE. Pienso que un script podria solucionar este problema.

Como hago para reemplazar "

Este es mi codigo:
[image: este es mi codigo html6]

Comment: Hola Gian, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo al [tour] y a [ask]. Tengo varias dudas: 1.- ¿HTML6? Hasta donde yo sé no existe una versión 6 de HTML. 2.- ¿Por qué quieres hacer ese replace en tiempo de ejecución? ¿No sería más fácil hacerlo antes?

Comment: Por favor en vez de añadir el código como imagen, SO te permite añadir código como texto y hasta código que podemos ejecutar aquí mismo. Por lo cual  añade bien tu código para que podamos ayudarte mejor y no tener que perder tiempo en hacerlo todo de nuevo. Y HTML6? Que yo sepa aun no hay HTML6.